# How to fetch the data of an osm object if osm ID is known?

Tags: openstreetmap

I am trying to fetch the details of an osm object using its osm id. I'm currently using nominatim's lookup to fetch data, but it only contains basic details. Is there any other way / API that can fetch all the details of the object?

Answer (score 0):

There is the [OSM API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_API).

Examples for retrieving element information:

- https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/4506300751
- https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/23922428
- https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/23922428/full
- https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/8557324
- https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/8557324/full

Note that this is mainly intended as an editing API. You can use it to perform small requests now and then. However, the OSM API is not intended for large bulk requests. See the [API usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/api/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In R I do :

```
osmObj <- opq_osm_id (type = "relation", id = osmID) %>%
    opq_string () %>%
    osmdata_sf ()
```

I can then use the object further. I am aware you haven't asked for R but I thought it might help nevertheless.